# Does deleting a class object delete all of a member vector's objects?

Tags: c++

Suppose you have a class like

```
class Manager {
   public:
     vector<Player> players;
     void AddSoManyPlayers();
}

void Manager::AddSoManyPlayers(){
   Player* player1 = new Player();
   Player* player2 = new Player();
   Player* player3 = new Player();
   Player* player4 = new Player();
   players.push_back(*player1);
   players.push_back(*player2);
   players.push_back(*player3);
   players.push_back(*player4);
}
```

And then you delete the `Manager` or let it go out of scope after adding `Player` objects to the `players` vector.

```
int main(){
  Manager manager;
  manager.AddSoManyPlayers();
  return 0;
}
```

Does every `Player` in `players` get their deconstructor called? I found when trying to clear the vector from `~Manager()` via `players.clear()` the compiler said I was trying to free memory twice, so I think I know the answer. But it's quite unexpected from what I've read - ie *there must always be a delete for every new*.

Late note: I am pre C++11

Comment: There are no deletes or news in your code.

Comment: there is no `new` in your code. so it's hard to think you will have to `delete` something

Comment: dont think to complicated, when your `Manager` goes out of scope then its member `player` goes out of scope and its destructor is called, no need for deletes, nothing to worry about

Comment: `players.clear()` is not `delete`.

Comment: _from ~Manager() via players.clear() the compiler said I was trying to free memory twice_ I don't think that that is true.

Comment: The code you posted contains type errors. Please read [mcve].

Comment: @melpomene `std::vector<T>::clear() does call the destructor for each element`

Comment: You have a vector of instances ob `Player` but you are pushing pointers. Unless your class bizarrely has an implicit conversion from pointer to itself, this won't compile.

Comment: @JDoe. How does that relate to anything I wrote?

Comment: Show your `~Manager()`

Comment: @JDoe. Beware that calling the destructor of a pointer does not mean that it deletes the object it's pointing. Destroying a `T` calls it's destructor, but destroying a `T*` just destroys the pointer (which does nothing).

Comment: You cant insert a Player* into a vector<Player>. You don't show real code!

Comment: Now your changed code leaks.

Comment: @JDoe. Why do you `new` objects, and store them by value? What's wrong with [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Stuck pre C++11, I guess I Should mention that somewhere

Answer (score 2):

> Does deleting a class object delete all of its vectors objects?

Yes. All sub objects are destroyed when the super object is destroyed.

> Does every Player in players get their deconstructor called?

Yes. All elements of container are destroyed when the container is destroyed.

---

However, the dynamic objects pointed by `playerX` are never deleted, and when those local pointers go out of scope at the end of `Manager::AddSoManyPlayers`, there is no way to delete them anymore.

---

> Then why, if I loop through the vector and explicitly delete each `Player` does the compiler complain about memory corruption/double delete? Where am I supposed to delete each `Player`?

As I said, the players within the vector are destroyed when the container is destroyed. You aren't supposed to delete them explicitly.

> But it's quite unexpected from what I've read - ie there must always be a delete for every new.

This is not the only rule of thumb to remember. Another rule is that the pointer to be deleted must be the one returned by `new`. You don't store those pointers in the vector, so you delete nothing from the vector. You store the pointers in the `playerX` variables, so those are the ones that must be deleted.

Even better: Don't create the dynamic objects in the first place. This is how you can create a new player into the vector without creating a dynamic one:

```
players.emplace_back();
```

And this is how you can create all 4 in one call:

```
players.resize(4 + players.size());
```

---

> I thought anything declared not as new will die out of scope, in this case `AddSoManyPlayers`

Indeed. That is why the `playerX` pointers are destroyed at the end of `AddSoManyPlayers` at which point the dynamic objects they point at can no longer be deleted.

> How else will the Player objects survive once the `AddSoManyPlayers` method is complete (goes out of scope)

`vector<Player> players` is not declared within the scope of `AddSoManyPlayers`, so it will not be destroyed at the end of it, and so its elements are not destroyed yet either, and so will survive the return.

It seems that you haven't this out yet, which may be the source of confusion: The objects in the vector are not the same object that is given as the argument to `push_back`. The objects in the vector are copies of that argument.

Comment: Then why, if I loop through the vector and explicitly delete each `Player` does the compiler complain about memory corruption/double delete? Where am I supposed to delete each `Player`?

Comment: @JDoe. Why are you using `new` in the first place?

Comment: @JDoe in vector there are no pointer elements so you can not delete those.

Comment: @JDoe. Your `std::vector` stores **copies** of your original objects. You should delete them at the end of `AddSoManyPlayers`, which raises a question of why do you need `new` in the first place.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius How else will the `Player` objects survive once the `AddSoManyPlayers` method is complete (goes out of scope)

Comment: @user2079303 User quantik says in another comment that these will be copies (when not using `new`). Is this acceptable? At the end of the day I'm just trying to write a generic object manager.

Comment: @JDoe. "_How else will the `Player` objects survive once the `AddSoManyPlayers` method is complete_" Did you read the first half of my comment? Once you `push_back`, the copy, of your original object is inserted into the `std::vector`. So the objects pointed to by your `playerX` pointers, are not the same objects as the objects that are stored in `std::vector` anymore. "_that these will be copies (when not using `new`)_" In your use-case, you are performing object copy anyway. [Example](https://ideone.com/PhOAXb).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Originally I created this system to store `Player*` pointers in the `players` vector instead of values. Then I was reading about this exact design pattern and read it was a very bad idea. I guess I just do not like the concept of creating an object and then putting a copy somewhere to manage it, instead of managing the actual object... it seems like its the opposite of what you should do.

Answer (score 1):

> Does every Player in players get their deconstructor called?

Yes it does. You have different issue in your code, you dynamically allocate 4 objects by `operator new`, put copy of them into `std::vector` and then let them leak. Copies of those in `std::vector` would be destroyed either if you call `clear()` explicitly or by destructor of `std::vector`, but originals would not get destroyed. You need to destroy them manually or use smart pointers instead of raw ones:

```
void Manager::AddSoManyPlayers(){
   Player* player1 = new Player();
   Player* player2 = new Player();
   Player* player3 = new Player();
   Player* player4 = new Player();
   players.push_back(*player1);
   players.push_back(*player2);
   players.push_back(*player3);
   players.push_back(*player4);
   delete player4;
   delete player3;
   delete player2;
   delete player1;
}
```

But it not clear why you need to allocate originals dynamically.

If your intention to dynamically allocate objects and let `Manager` to maintain their lifetime, then use smart pointers:

```
class Manager {
   public:
     std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Player>> players;
     void AddSoManyPlayers() {
         players.emplace_back( new Player );
         ...
     }
}
```

then you would not put a copy into vector and your objects would be properly deleted by destructor (and you do not need to call `std::vector::clear()` explicitly

Comment: Because I thought anything declared not as `new` will die out of scope, in this case `AddSoManyPlayers`. So I created them as `new` and then would rely on `Manager` to `delete` them later.

Comment: Then you need your vector to have (smart) pointers instead of objects by value.

Comment: So if I declared my players via `Player player` instead of using `new`, added them to the `vector`, and then left the scope, the vector would now be full of what?

Comment: @JDoe. Copies of the original player objects that you created on the stack

Comment: @quantik Is that a sensible thing to do? Wouldn't I want the original objects?

Comment: @JDoe. In this case presumably you would only want to access the objects in the vector, then no you wouldn't.